# Session id changes between two requests

Tags: java, spring, firefox, flex4

I am using session id to store files uploaded by a particular user and when user clicks on a button, these files get downloaded. However, there is a problem that I am facing. When I am creating the file, the session id which comes in is different than any other request within same session by same user. Which results in two different session ids and due to which user faces problem in downloading that file. Same thing works file in `IE`. This happens only in Firefox. Jaxb is used for web services and flex for GUI. Can someone help determining what is going wrong here and in which layer?

Comment: Is there any login activity? It's possible the session is invalidated on login.

Comment: no.. there is no login happening at the same time.

Comment: How do you do the session tracking? Cookies or URL?

Comment: Is it possible that cookies are turned off in the firefox browser?

Comment: session tracking is done using cookies

Comment: cookies are turned on. And other functionality work fine. Session id is same for all other request except this upload request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may occur based on the fact that file-upload (and maybe download, too) in ActionScript will generate a separate session with its own lifecycle. I faced this problem in one of my Flex-based applications where I used PHP for the backend.

The problem was that a user had to have the ability to upload media files but only when he is logged in to the application. When starting a new file upload ActionScript will process the upload under a separate session with its own session ID. I figured it out only because the user has been redirected back to the login-screen when the upload started due to conflicting sessions for user and file upload.

You should consult the API documentation of ActionScript's [FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) class to get a starting point what exactly will happen during file upload/download.

The problem that you have that issue only in Firefox can be originating from your Flash Player version installed for Firefox. Maybe there are some bugs or other issues which are browser-specific.